# SQL SERVER returning wrong result when called from ASP.NET (always returning the result from last request)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, iis, asp.net-2.0

### Heading

I have this code:

```
string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connStr);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTestProcedure", connection);
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
int test = int.Parse(Request.QueryString["test"]);
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Test", test);

SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(command);

DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

For some reason, it's always returning the result of the last request.
Example:

- 1st request &test=111  returns no result
- 2nd request &test=222  returns result for 111
- 3rd request &test=111  returns result for 222
- 4th request &test=111  returns result for 111

Requests can be coming from differant clients, the result is the same.

The stored procedure always return the good result when executed directly from SQL Server Management Studio.

The website is running on a shared host and seems to be on heavy load when this happens.

Is there any way it could be code related or is this server related?

Comment: Does this happen ALL the time or only when the system has a heavy load?

Comment: Not totally related to your issue but...http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: Only when it is under heavy load. Other random problems also happen on other websites that run on the same server during these times.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks I will have a look.

Comment: In which event is this code called? Is this a normal page cycle or a partial?

Comment: Is the webcontrol/page that shows this data cached?

Comment: Last question, Does the stored procedure make changes to the database (are the results/requests stored in a staging table)

Comment: This is called from a method that is called in the Page_Load of an .aspx page. I don't have access to server settings but I really it's locally cached, there isn't any services like cloudflare either. The page is the connection and receives the ID of the User Group so that you can select your username.

Comment: The result is an union on 2 select statement.

Comment: I got nothing, I can reasonably say that the issue is NOT the code since the routine works when there is no load on the system. From you're description it sounds like several different programs are all trying to use the same data at the same time. This is causing the server to respond slower than it normally does

Answer (score 0):

The server gave me another clue today:

I was browsing page B and shortly after I opened page A.

Page A crashed with this error:

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Could not find stored procedure 'spThatIsOnlyPresentOnPageB'.

Seems like the server has trouble processing SqlCommands correctly in general.

Time to change the server. Thanks for the ideas guys!